# Why grub2 is not starting when external HD (containing a clonezilla backup image) is plugged in?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a Dell XPS 9570 with dual boot setting (ubuntu alongside windows 10). Normally grub2 menu works like a charm, except a very special case; when an external HD containing a Clonezilla image* is plugged in, then GRUB2 never shows up and windows boot automatically. The problem is not associated with the existence of an external HD in general, but only if this HD contains a Clonezilla image into one of its directories. Any idea why that happens?

edit. *It is an image of a whole disk with a dual boot on it, so I suppose it has a /boot/efi partition as well. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WarrU.png) is a listing of what the Clonezilla image includes if it helps.

Comment: Was the image of a complete disk or just a partition?  Just taking a wild guess, but an image of complete disk might include grub copy too, causing interference.

Comment: Does the closezilla backup contain the EFI System Partition (ESP) as well? Are you trying to boot from this backup?

Comment: @user68186 seems like the OP is saying that only this HD stops grub from loading, maybe it is a complete copy of windows and the computer is set to boot from it first, bypassing the internal boot loaders.

Comment: @crip659 It is possible. We won't know until OP edits the the question and adds the information we requested.

Comment: I updated the description. The Clonezilla Image is an Image of a whole image with dual boot, so I think it does contain a /boot/efi partition. My question is why the system bypasses the internal boot loaders, although I have set it to boot firstly from the internal SSD and not the external one.